# Facebook still getting my real IP even with TOR + cURL + PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl, tor

I'm making a login to Facebook using cURL, and I'm using a TOR proxy for this login. Here's my code:

```
function loginOnFacebook($login_email, $login_pass)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Proxy configuration, very important!
        if(isset($params['t']))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);     
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'charset_test=€,´,€,´,水,Д,Є&email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Login');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Charset: utf-8','Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.7,bn-bd;q=0.3','Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5')); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd ());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd ());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "user_agent");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://m.facebook.com");

        $fbMain = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

        $url = 'https://m.facebook.com/home.php?refid=18';

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $demo_mac=curl_exec($ch);
        $effectiveUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

        if($effectiveUrl == $url)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

You can see that I'm checking the `$param -t` to use a TOR proxy over port 9050.

It works, I'm checking this way:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 50; $i++)
{
    $ch = curl_init('http://icanhazip.com/');

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);

    if(isset($params['t']))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 7);     
    }

    $myIp = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
    print($myIp);
}
```

This code will check my public IP on `http://icanhazip.com/` and print it to me, and it's working, I'm getting a TOR IP.

But, when I try to login on Facebook using this system,  I'm still getting my real IP address.

[image]

Can someone help me to identify what's going on?

Comment: You are calling `curl_exec()` twice, but you are setting the proxy config only once. Make sure curl is not dropping the connection between the two requests and bypassing the proxy on the second request..

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still doesn't work, even removing the second call on the loginOnFacebook() :(
Keep in mind that these 2 snippets aren't executed together, the second one is just to test if the proxy is working!

Thanks Remy!

Comment: For Facebook you should their onion service at https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion This ensures that the whole connection never leaves the Tor network.

Comment: How should i proceed with this? since i can't directly curl this host :c, i get "could not resolve host"

Answer (score 0):

Historically every bit of information has been used to reidentify a user. I heart google had even worked on a login without password: based on the users behavior. In short: We are not as autonomous as we believed, but predictable to a point. Whatever you want to do further: Keep in mind, that not only query strings, IP-addresses and browser names are getting used to identify users, but also habits, typing speed, ping times and such. In fact there are so many ways, that even once your script works it will require regular security checks to keep it up to date with the development of such methods. I do not see any issues with your code, so I will assume that this has something to do with non traditional technology.

From history to the future: We have some new bits in the SSL protocol, which have not specifically been created to do session management, but might offer that possibility as a side effect. Neither of those I have seen implemented, but I consider OCSP stapling and ALPN to be good candidates.

- First of and less probable seems OCSP to me, which 'caches' the ssl certificate, so that the server knows, that your client was there. If facebook had a certificate authority under its control it could simply save your address there and reuse it, whenever you use your cached certificate- sry nsa ;)
- Second there is ALPN, which allows to use http2 and switch over to another protocol, like UDP and this won't work with your local TOR (https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Tunnel_UDP_over_Tor). It might be possible to establish a second connection over UDP to completely circumvent your proxy. I would therefore try to disable ALPN for now with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN, 1);`- sry google ;)

I can only hope that this will help you, because I haven't tried it. In any case should you read, understand and manually set every single setopt option and never trust the default values in order to be on the savest side possible. That is because curls dependencies, like libssl are always free to use configuration files and caches on their own. So that it won't even be enough to check all curl options, but also those they use. On the other hand curl's options are the best point to start, because they allow to disable unnecessary features of curl, which I would therefore do as good as possible.

Comment: And once you try: Also make sure, that your current session cache gets cleared somehow, preferable by setting `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` to TRUE

Comment: Still no results :/... I tried the CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_ALPN but it doesn't recognize this constant :X

Comment: Oh! I took that out of the C documentation. The variable might be called different in PHP

Comment: setting `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` to `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0` may do the same.

Comment: Oh i see :P, was able to change the http version now, but it doesn't work either, facebook still gets the real IP kkkkk, if there's no way, do you know some other way i could accomplish this without using any facebook API or so...?